# Order by a value of an arbitrary attribute in hstore

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I have records like these:

```
id, hstore_col
1,  {a: 1, b: 2}
2,  {c: 3, d: 4}
3,  {e: 1, f: 5}
```

How to order them by a maximum/minimum value inside hstore for **any** attribute?

The result should be like this(order by lowest):

```
id, hstore_col
1,  {a: 1, b: 2}
3,  {e: 1, f: 5}
2,  {c: 3, d: 4}
```

I know, I can only order them by specific attribute like this: `my_table.hstore_fields -> 'a'`, but it doesn't work for my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to an array using `avals` and cast the resulting array from text to ints. Then sort the array and order the results by the 1st element of the sorted array.

```
select * from mytable
order by (sort(avals(attributes)::int[]))[1]
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/84f31/5

Comment: Does this mean that

    ORDER BY greatest(avals(attributes)::int[])   

would also work?

Comment: @KirkRoybal it would not work because `greatest` returns the largest of its arguments and would treat the array as a single argument

Answer (score 2):

If you know all of the elements, you can just piece them all together like this:

```
ORDER BY greatest(my_table.hstore_fields -> 'a', my_table.hstore_fields -> 'b',my_table.hstore_fields -> 'c', my_table.hstore_fields -> 'd', my_table.hstore_fields -> 'e', my_table.hstore_fields -> 'f')
```

or

```
ORDER BY least(my_table.hstore_fields -> 'a', my_table.hstore_fields -> 'b',my_table.hstore_fields -> 'c', my_table.hstore_fields -> 'd', my_table.hstore_fields -> 'e', my_table.hstore_fields -> 'f')
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `svals` you can create an exploded version of the `hstore_col`'s values - then you can sort on those values and get the first entry from each of them.  There is doubtlessly a *much* more efficient way to do this, but here's a first pass:

```
select my_table.id, my_table.hstore_col
from my_table
join (
    select id, svals(hstore_col) as hstore_val
    from my_table
) exploded_table
    on my_table.id = exploded_table.id
group by my_table.id, my_table.hstore_col
order by my_table.id, exploded_table.hstore_val desc
```